# Dog has skin disease

Tags: dogs, skin-condition

I'm really disturbed by my dog's skin condition. I took her to the vet a few months ago and they diagnosed it as an age spot and allergies. I knew they were wrong and it's much worse now. Just look at the following picture of it with her fur wetted by me.

**What is going on?**

[image]

Comment: what breed? Actually looks a lot like my scnauzer cross does. and he had terrible skin as a puppy

Comment: golden retriever. when she goes outside she loves to roll on her back, and this has to be why.

Comment: How old is your dog?

Comment: i dont know precisely at the moment but she is old. at least 10 surely. probably close to 15.

Comment: Looks like the hair is thinning, other than that her skin looks OK. Might be why you may think that the spots are getting worse? Dogs can have black pigmentation normally and as they age.

Comment: @RebeccaRVT its not the big spots but the small ones that worry me, and how its gotten much worse fairly quickly, and how she rolls on her back cause it bothers her. zoom in on the little dark spots. those are not age spots, to me. im no vet but its troubling.

Comment: @ColbyRay hard to say from the photo, turns blurry when I zoom in. Best case would be to go to veterinary dermatologist.